# How to Set Secondary Axis(AxisX2) Minimum and Maximum different from Primary Axis(AxisX) in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, data-visualization, mschart

I am trying to plot a Chart in WinForms using `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` with different ranges for AxisX and AxisX2,

```
chartArea1.AxisX.Minimum=0;
chartArea1.AxisX.Maximum=600;
chartArea1.AxisX2.Minimum=0;
chartArea1.AxisX2.Maximum=300;
```

AxisX Labels range (0-600) is displayed in AxisX2 instead of range (0-300). Please help me to display AxisX2 labels instead of AxisX labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and It works for me if I add this line of code:

```
  private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
           //Added some point just for an  example

            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(1, 1);
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(2, 2);
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(3, 3);
            chart1.Series["Series1"].XAxisType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisType.Secondary;
        }
```

I checked out in my `Form1.Designer.cs` I have:

```
chartArea1.AxisX.Maximum = 600D;
chartArea1.AxisX.Minimum = 0D;
chartArea1.AxisX2.Maximum = 300D;
chartArea1.AxisX2.Minimum = 0D;
```

This should do the trick.